# Prove $f(x) = |x - 1| + |x + 2|$ is not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $c = 1$. 
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} \frac{|x-1|+|x+2| - (0 + 3)}{x - 1} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} \frac{-(x-1) + (x + 2) - 3}{x - 1} = ?$

From here, I know I want to get rid of the (x+2) and -3 on the numerator, but not sure how, since I am not allowed to take limits of a single term only.

Comment: Who told you that you cannot take the limit of a single term?

Comment: My math professor last spring, when handing back midterms. If I have the above expression, I cannot take $lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-}$ for only $(x+2)$ while not doing so for $(x-1)$

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Is it allowed because LH and RH direction limit of (x - 1) is not the same, but it is for (x + 2), so we can substitute in x= 1?

Comment: It’s premature to worry about the individual term $x+2$, when you can simplify the numerator first.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh thank you Erick. Didn't see that

Comment: It is sufficient to show that even one of the summands is not differentiable at some point. So, focus only on the first term, say.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

For $x<1$:

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1}
& = & \frac{-(x-1) + x+2 -3}{x-1} \\
& = & \frac{-(x-1) + x -1}{x-1} \\
& = & -\frac{x-1}{x-1} + \frac{x -1}{x-1} \\
& = & -1 + 1 = 0
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1^-}0 = 0$.

For $x>0$:

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1}
& = & \frac{x-1 + x+2 -3}{x-1} \\
& = & \frac{x-1 + x -1}{x-1} \\
& = & \frac{x-1}{x-1} + \frac{x -1}{x-1} \\
& = & 1 + 1 = 2
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence, $\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1^+}2 = 2$.

So, the function is not differentiable at $x=1$.

Similarly, it is not differentiable at $x=-2$. You may check this for yourself as a small exercise.